# API XML/JSON Response and VBA to parse it

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I have API which gives me the stock price based on constructed URL with token and symbol,this API returns is web based and returns XML/JSON format data in `<root></root>` and data in it. Below is an example.

```xml
 <root>
     <n5323 type="float">31.35</n5323 >
     <n3221 type="float">9.06</n3221 >
 </root>
```

I would like to retrieve price in Excel using VBA (`31.35` and `9.06`), please help me on this how to achieve. Not that the `n5323` and `n3221` are generated dynamically and are different every time.

My VBA code is as below

```vb
Dim strXMLSite As String
Dim objXMLHTTP As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Dim objXMLDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim objXMLNodexbrl As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim objXMLNodeDIIRSP As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Set objXMLHTTP = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Set objXMLDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

strXMLSite = "http://testserver/volume/daily?token=' + token$ + '&ticker='+Symbol$+'"

objXMLHTTP.Open "POST", strXMLSite, False
objXMLHTTP.send
objXMLDoc.LoadXML (objXMLHTTP.responseText)

Set objXMLNodexbrl = objXMLDoc.SelectSingleNode("root")
Set objXMLNodeDIIRSP = objXMLNodexbrl.SelectSingleNode("root")

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J1").Value = objXMLNodeDIIRSP.Text
```

Comment: Add reference to `Microsoft XML, v6.0`, instantiate a `DOMDocument` and `loadXML` the response.

Comment: could you please put code snipet here ? I have updated my code in main post...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSXML “The system cannot locate the resource specified”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4041687/11683)

Comment: I got the response using my code above in orignial post in xmldoc  but can any body tell me how to parse this from response , below is the xml response I wan to parse and this n321 and n314 are generated randomely.<root>
     <n5323 type="float">31.35</n5323 >
     <n3221 type="float">9.06</n3221 >
 </root>

Comment: Try to replace the string `"http://testserver/volume/daily?token=' + token$ + '&ticker='+Symbol$+'"` with `"http://testserver/volume/daily?token=" & token$ & "&ticker=" & Symbol$`, also make sure that the strings in `token` and `Symbol` variables are URL-encoded.

Comment: It is already working , my now question is how to parse  XML response out of that, please see above post I pasted XML response which needs to be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what node names there are, you enumerate nodes.

```vb
Dim n As IXMLDOMNode
For Each n In objXMLDoc.documentElement.childNodes
  Debug.Print n.nodeName, n.Text
Next
```